# rspec and carrierwave - how set an image url directly (BYPASS carrierwave uploader during testing)

Tags: rspec, carrierwave

I'm writing some rspec specs where an object's widgetpic field needs to point to an actual image, but *without* using the carrierwave uploader.

When in test, I just want to bypass the uploader and manually set a test picture's url. Specifically I have a few test images online and simply want to have `foo.widgetpic.url` to return some fixed location:"http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/test_pix/test1.png"

The Widget model has:

```
mount_uploader :widgetpic, WidgetPicUploader
```

So in my FactoryGirl factory I assume I need to do something like this

```
trait :test_pic do
   SOMETHING "http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/test_pix/test1.png"
end
```

I tried setting widgetpic_url and remote_widgetpic_url but that didn't work (widgetpic.url still returns my default 'no image' image defined in my uploader).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that something else is broken about your uploader, not the factory. Can you post your carrierwave configuration?

That aside, the correct factory syntax for remote images is remote_< resource >_url:

```
trait :test_pic do
  remote_widgetpic_url "http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/test_pix/test1.png"
end
```

However, be aware that by doing this, CarrierWave is not being bypassed. CarrierWave will fetch the remote image for you and use the downloaded image to re-upload to the location specified in your uploader. You can use this technique in conjunction with something like [WebMock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) or [VCR](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) to emulate and/or record the HTTP request and play it back.

A simpler approach might be to use the mocking capabilities built into [Fog](https://github.com/fog/fog) to simulate the upload for the test. That way, you can just place a dummy image in your factory:

```
factory :widget do   
  # ...

  widgetpic Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(File.open(
    File.join(
      File.dirname(__FILE__), '../fixtures/images/your_image_here.png')))
end
```

That image will be used to simulate the upload, but will not be posted to the location on S3 and you can test the upload from end-to-end.